# How to have an image click event in colorbox onload method

Tags: c#, jquery

I am using a **colorbox** plugin with iframe. The `iframe` source is another HTML page which has a image courosal. Where i need to write a click event to get the id of the clicked image.

The ordinary click event on the HTML page in document ready is not working, i tried with live as well. Also i tried having a click event inside the colorbox onload function and failed.

Its an Web application with **asp.net 4.0**.

Please help me out on this to write a click event.

The Script where i am calling the colorbox

```
$(".iframe").colorbox({ iframe: true, width: "70%", height: "80%" });

    $(".iframe").colorbox({
        onLoad: function () {
            alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content');
            $('ul#boutiquegallery img').on('click', function () {
                alert('clciked img');
            });
        },
        onComplete: function () {
            alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content');

        },
        //onClosed: function () { alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
    });
```

The script that i have tried in My HTML

```
(function ($) {
    $('#boutique').boutique();

    //$("iframe.cboxIframe").contents().find($('ul#boutique img').live('click', function () {
    //    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    //    alert(id);
    //}));

    //$("iframe.cboxIframe").load(function () {
    //    alert('hi');
    //    // write your code here
    //    $('a').click(function () {
    //        alert('clciked');
    //    });
    //    $('img').live('click', function () {
    //        alert('clciked img');
    //    });
    //});
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
        //$('img').on('click', function () {
        //    alert('clciked img');
        //});
    //$('iframe.cboxIframe').load(function () {
    //    $('iframe.cboxIframe').contents().find('img').live({
    //        click: function () {
    //            alert('clicked img');
    //        }
    //    });

    //});

});
```

Comment: thanks for the reply kannan. here i am posting my code.

Comment: The code dude, and you can also put the same at some place like jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/  and share the link with us, we can tweak it and help you.

Comment: sorry dear, i am very new here. i just updated the post with code. please have  a look

Answer (score 0):

Try this extra step:

```
var iFrameDoc = $(".iframe").contentDocument || $(".iframe").contentWindow.document;
iFrameDoc.colorbox({ 
         // rest of the code is the same as yours after here
        onLoad: function () {
            alert('onLoad: colorbox has started to load the targeted content');
            $('ul#boutiquegallery img').on('click', function () {
                alert('clciked img');
            });
        },
        onComplete: function () {
            alert('onComplete: colorbox has displayed the loaded content');

        },
        //onClosed: function () { alert('onClosed: colorbox has completely closed'); }
    });
```

iframes can be tricky when trying to access DOM objects :)

Comment: Hi, i used the same code that u have given above, and its not working. Is there any other way of doing it on my HTML page ?.

Comment: in my previously posted code the onload alert was worked, where as the click event was not worked.

Comment: Thanks, kannan for ur valuable time. i have found the fix.

Answer (score 0):

The below code inside my HTML page has done the trick.

```
 $(document).on('click', 'img', function () {
        alert('hi dsad');
        alert($(this).attr('src'));
    });
```